# Why does my unit test for calculator GUI is showing AssertionError?

Tags: python, unit-testing

We have a project to create an calculator GUI and it needs to have unit test.

I try to create a unit test for the equal button. This is the code:

```
def btneq_clicked(*args):
    try:
        ans = disp.get()
        ans = eval(ans)
        disp.delete(0, END)
        disp.insert(0, ans)

    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Value Error", "Check your values and operators")
```

My unit test is this:

```
class TestCalc(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_plus(self):
        disp = "1 + 2"
        ans = btneq_clicked(eval(disp))
        self.assertEqual(ans, 3)
```

If I run it, this shows up: AssertionError: None != 3
Please help me correct my unit test

Comment: Because `btneq_clicked` doesn't return anything.  What did you want it to return?

Comment: I want to check if the calculator is working. How should I code the unit test?

Comment: You would fill in the `disp` cell with your formula (using delete/insert), then call `btneq_clicked`, then fetch the new `disp` contents and verify the answer.